# Vmag versus VpgMag in GSC 2.3 catalogue

Tags: magnitude

I tried to find out the magnitude in V for V* V881 Per.

Here are my results:

[SIMBAD:](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=V881%20Per&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id)  $11.09$    (Fluxes->V)

[GSC 2.3:](http://gsss.stsci.edu/webservices/vo/CatalogSearch.aspx?RAH=02&RAM=59&RAS=53&DSN=%20&DD=38&DM=01&DS=48&FORMAT=HTML&CAT=GSC241&SR=0.00166666666666667&)  $10.9815$  (VpgMag) and  $10.887$   (Vmag)

Which of VpgMag or Vmag in GSC 2.3 correpsonds to SIMBAD V-flux?

For each star [GSC 2.3](http://gsss.stsci.edu/webservices/GSC2/WebForm.aspx) cites two values for magnitude in V so which of the two should I use?

Comment: V881 Per is a variable star, so its brightness changes over time. According to AAVSO.ORG it varies between 10.8 and 11.2 (approximately). Which brightness would you like to use?

Answer (score 1):

Your "GSC 2.3" entry is actually from GSC 2.4.1, as shown in the header lines containing the string "GSC241".

According to the [record structure for GSC 2.4.1](https://outerspace.stsci.edu/display/GC/GSC+2.4.1+Record+Structure), Vmag is "V-band magnitude" while VpgMag is "Photographic V-band magnitude". The magnitudes are associated with a [code that describes what bandpass/filter they are using](https://outerspace.stsci.edu/display/GC/Bandpass+Codes). In your case, the VpgMagCode field is 1, which corresponds to the emulsion+filter IIaD+W12 (au used by the Palomar Quick-V survey). Confusingly the VMagCode field is set to 3, which corresponds to a Johnson B-magnitude. Perhaps this is an error in the catalogue and should be 4 (Johnson V-magnitude)? The [source code](https://outerspace.stsci.edu/display/GC/Source+Codes) of 19 indicates the magnitude is from APASS (the [AAVSO Photometric All-Sky Survey](https://www.aavso.org/apass)). The APASS website provides some further information on the magnitudes used:

> Johnson B and V were chosen to extend the Tycho calibration to fainter magnitudes and to match the many archival published datasets. These passbands can be easily used to create sequences for any VSX / GCVS star. Sloan passbands provide a direct link to the SDSS, SkyMapper, PanSTARRs etc. surveys, and provide a homogeneous catalog of brighter stars.  The Johnson B and V magnitudes are on the Vega system; the Sloan u',g',r',i',z_s and Z magnitudes are on the AB system.

A few more details on the Johnson magnitude system can be found on [this web page](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Edfabricant/huchra/ay145/mags.html): the system is set up so that the star Vega has a V-magnitude of 0.03, and the colors (e.g. B-V) are 0. Details of the Johnson-Cousins UBVRI filters can be found on the website of the [Leibniz-Institut für Astrophysik Potsdam](https://www.aip.de/en/research/facilities/stella/instruments/data/johnson-ubvri-filter-curves).

The details of the magnitude in SIMBAD can be obtained by going to the reference listed there: [Norton et al. (2007)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007A&A...467..785N). This paper indicates that the magnitude is from the SuperWASP photometric survey. The details of the filter the SuperWASP survey uses can be found on the [SVO Filter Profile Service](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/index.php?id=WASP/SuperWASP.SW&&mode=browse&asttype=astro&gname=WASP&gname2=SuperWASP). Norton et al. (2007) describe the value in section 3 of the paper:

> the mean SuperWASP magnitude,
> defined as $-2.5 \log_{10} (F/10^6)$ where $F$ is the mean SuperWASP
> flux in microVegas; it is a pseudo-V magnitude which is comparable to the Tycho V magnitude

A microVega is a millionth of the flux from Vega. Note that the above formula implies a V-magnitude for Vega of 0, in contrast to the Johnson system.

As for which one you should use, it depends on what you are doing. If you're comparing with other SuperWASP results (or perhaps objects in the Tycho survey), use the SuperWASP V-magnitude. If you're comparing with other magnitudes in the Johnson system, go with Vmag from GSC 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Vmag is the visual magnitude in the V wavelength, viz. 551 nm, whereas Vpgmag is the *photographic* magnitude in the same wavelength. Photographic emulsions—and now CCD and CMOS detectors—have a different sensitivity curve than the human eye, hence the difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you suggest any particular (introductory) bibliography on this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_magnitude is very introductory…